# What to Do with Six Pack Boxes

Tags: environment

I collected a lot of six pack boxes to put bottles of homebrew in.  Now, I've got a better container.  Since I can't recycle six pack boxes, is there anything I could do with them other than throw them out?

Comment: Has whoever does your recycling stated that they don't accept 6-pack boxes? Where I live, it's just treated as straight cardboard and they'll take it.

Comment: @fire.eagle: Their FAQ said no cardboard with waxy coating.  I'm assuming the glossy finish on most of the six packs qualify as "waxy coating".

Comment: I don't think that's waxy coating.  Waxy coating would be like the boxes cucumbers come in at the grocery store.  They're corrugated cardboard literally coated in wax.

Comment: Out of curiosity (and I seem to be rough on 6pack carriers) what is your "better container" for bottles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not wax coated. And you can recycle them. Does your recycling center accept cardboard boxes from children's toys? Do they accept magazines? Do they accept old posters? All pretty much the same thing. You'll know wax cardboard when you see it. It does not get as easily damaged by moisture as regular cardboard. And you usually have to seek it out.

Answer (score 2):

Since recycling won't take them, you might try talking to the store you bought the 6-packs from originally. Every liquor store I have been in has a "build your own 6-pack" option from their singles, and they have a basket of those boxes sitting out for people to use for their selection. They might be willing to take them back to reuse for that.

I will note that I have never tried this before, but it seems reasonable that they would take at least a few.

Answer (score 2):

Next time you're at your local brew shop see if they'll take em off your hands. They might leave them as a freebie for anyone who wants to take em.

The brew shop I go to sometimes has used equipment left by brewers for cheap or free.

MoreBeer sells blank 6 pack carriers for $0.95, so there's probably a homebrewer who'd pick em up.
http://morebeer.com/view_product/15640/102304/6_Pack_Carrier

Answer (score 2):

If you know anyone that likes to wash and/or detail their car(s), they could use the six-pack boxes to store their car-care products. It would be worth asking them if they would like to use your six-pack boxes for storing the bottles of products.

One example of how i use them: I store the products that deal with interior in one six-pack box labeled "Interior," the products for dealing with wheels and tires in one labeled "Wheels," etc.

Comment: Good idea.  I think I'll use some of them to store my cycling stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking of covering a wall in my brewery (aka the garage) with various six-pack boxes -- probably just the side, cut out.  I have a lot of six-packs as well, but my recycling company takes them, so they'll take the cuttings or any that I don't want.